# how to write a OQL query comparing with number

Tags: oql

this is the OQL query i have written

```
select * from myClass.Session ses where ses.creationTime <= 1391171576144
```

I get following error when i execute the query

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1391171576144"

    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

the attribute value is

### Type|Name        |Value

### long|creationTime|1391172135198

Answer (score 0):

You need to add L at the end; otherwise, 1391171576144 is interpreted as an integer:

```
select * from myClass.Session ses where ses.creationTime <= 1391171576144L
```